# How to focus on a tab in sitecore?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sitecore, sitecore6

I have 2 tabs as a Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link with one link. Now when the page is opening up, I want to focus on the first one. I wrote this code but seems like its only hitting the 0th index 2 times. So I am getting both tabs as selected items. Here is the code:

```
protected void rptTab_ItemBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Item i = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
            Link hlTabLink;
            HtmlControl liHTML;
            liHTML = e.Item.FindControl("liTabTest") as HtmlControl;
            hlTabLink = e.Item.FindControl("hlTabLink") as Link;
            hlTabLink.Target = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(i);
            hlTabLink.DataSource = i.Paths.FullPath;
            hlTabLink.Field = "Title";
            String liContainerId;
            switch (hlTabLink.TabIndex) //Switch case statements for the tab navigation. 
            {
                case 0:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    liHTML.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);                   
                    break;
                case 1:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    hlTabLink.CssClass = "tab-label TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    liContainerId = "tab-label last";
                    hlTabLink.Attributes.Add("class", liContainerId);
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Case 0 is hitting 2 times. As you can see the tabs are in the repeater. Here is the markup for that:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptTab" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptTab_ItemBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li id= "liTabTest" runat = "server">
                    <a>
                        <sc:Link ID = "hlTabLink" Field = "scTabLink" runat ="server"></sc:Link>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like TabIndex either wasn't populated yet, perhaps due to data binding completing before the dom is updated. Could easily be a problem with the sequence of events and updates etc. Otherwise, maybe TabIndex is never getting populated?

Did you check that property at a later stage?

Finally, isn't there another event you can hook which triggers when all items are bound? With your current code you will have to hard-code the n'th item as the last item (2 in your sample), which is easy to forget when you add another item at a later time. If you can find such an event you could loop through the items by an indexed for loop and having all items there would know what the length would be, meaning you don't have to hardcode that value.